# Origin of the notation for statistical divergence

Tags: probability-theory, notation, information-theory

The unusual notation $D(P||Q)$ seems to be universally used for statistical divergences (e.g. KL divergence). What is the origin of this notation, and do the double bars (pipe symbols) have any significance in statistics/probability or information theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kullback and Leibler did not originate the $D(P||Q)$ notation. In their paper "On Information and Sufficiency", Ann. Math. Stat, 22(1):79-86, 1951, they use $$I_{1:2}(E)=\frac{1}{\mu_1(E)}\int_{E} \,d\mu_1(x) \log \frac{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)},$$ stated for a set $E\subseteq S$ of the sample space $S.$ They attribute this notation to Halmos and Savage.

Shannon doesn't seem to use it either, as far as I can tell by a cursory look. Maybe an information theorist (Cover? Wolfowitz(?), Gallager(?, but in his classic book it only appears as a problem, for the discrete case, and without a symbol, just as a sum!), Wyner(?),Csiszar?) later on adopted the notation.

The two vertical bars may be there to stop people think it is a conditional distribution.

Comment: Sure, but why not use the notation D(P, Q), which is, you know, the default notation for a binary function?

Comment: @Aqwis: In information theory, it is common to write $H(X,Y)$ for the entropy of the joint distribution of two random variables $X$ and $Y$.  You would want to do the same with the KL divergence, for example, to denote the divergence between $(X,Y)$ and $(X',Y')$, so you would either need too many  parentheses or a different separator symbol.  I'm sure there is a justification along these lines in the book of Cover and Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

Double bars are not universally acknowledged notation for statistical distances. Instead of double bars, coma can be preferred. Even in information theory society, double bars are not a must to be used to indicate the distance between the probability measures. However, it is quite likely that such creative notations might have come to existence by some exotic information theory guys.

Comment: Aligned with your answer I found this answer also compelling: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269183/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-vertical-bar-in-this-kl-divergence-equation

Comment: Moreover, I checked the notation in "Probability for Statistics and Machine Learning" and it is not using this double bar notation, which confirms that it is a creative notation by an information theory fellow. It could potentially also be related to some of the illustrations made on pages 7 to 10 of the Cover and Thomas' book!